# Java anonymous Inner Class: must implement the inherited abstract method

Tags: java, interface, polymorphism, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I am not able to understand the below code which I was experimenting.

I have one class "ExtendMe", one interface "Implementable" and another class "ImplementYikes" that will extend the class "ExtendMe" and implements "Implementable" as below:

```
class ImplementYikes extends ExtendMe implements Implementable{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Yikes y1 = new Yikes();
        Yikes y2 = new childYikes();

        y1.display();
        y2.display();

        Implementable iii = new Implementable() {

            @Override
            public void iDisplay() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        };


        ExtendMe eee = new ExtendMe() {
            @Override
            void cDisplay() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.cDisplay();
            }
        };

    }

}


interface Implementable{
    void iDisplay();
}

class ExtendMe {
    void cDisplay(){

    }
}
```

**Problem:** I do not get a compiler error while creating the "eee" reference, as you can clearly see the anonymous inner class is OVERRIDING the "cDisplay" method. However, when implement the same logic with the interface, by creating a reference "iii", I am being prompted with a compile time error, stating that I am supposed to be IMPLEMENTING the methods from the Interface, even when I am overriding the method in the Anonymous inner class.

**Error Straight from the IDE:**

```
The type ImplementYikes must implement the inherited abstract method Implementable.iDisplay()
```

**I have come to the below conclusion:**

1. The JVM throws that error, since we do not have a default implementation for the method "iDisplay". That is, overriding should happen before we have a BASE-IMPLEMENTATION-IN-PLACE.

Comment: Got the solution, May be I was too hasty to post the question. The JVM throws the compile time error, because it is expecting the class "ImplementYikes" to provide the implementation of the methods since it is implementing the interface.But we are overriding the methods of the interface under the Anonymous class. Solved the problem by removing the "implements Implementable" from the "ImplementYikes" class. Since the Anonymous class implicitly implements the interface - "Implementable"

Comment: the above error means that you need to implement/override the method of your interface in your `ImplementYikes` class

Comment: Complle errors are printed, not thrown.